# Usual argument in algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let R be a ring with 1, and P a prime ideal of $R[x]$, then
$$\phi: \dfrac{R}{P \cap R}[x] \to \dfrac{R[x]}{P}$$ given by $(r_n+P\cap R)x^n+...+(r_0 + P \cap R)x^0 \to (r_nx^n+...+r_0x^0)+P$ is an epimorphism and
$$Ker (\phi) = \{(r_n+P\cap R)x^n+...+(r_0 + P \cap R)x^0 \in \dfrac{R}{P \cap R}[x] \left / \right   (r_nx^n+...+r_0x^0) \in P \}$$

An easy verification shows that $Ker(\phi) \cap\dfrac{R}{P \cap R} = 0$ and $Ker(\phi)$ is prime in $\dfrac{R}{P \cap R}[x]$.

I am studying an proof and he claims that from this **we need only consider the case where $P \cap R = 0$.**
I am trying to understand why we can claim that.

I know that by isomorphism theorem we have that $\dfrac{\dfrac{R}{P \cap R}[x]}{Ker (\phi)} \cong \dfrac{R[x]}{P}$.

Does $Ker(\phi) \cap\dfrac{R}{P \cap R} = 0$ implies $P \cap R = 0$?

Comment: I think it is useful to know the entire step in that proof where this is claimed.

Comment: It is from an article. The author needs the hypothesis $P \cap R = 0$ to proof the main theorem. I wrote everything, this is the article https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82204709.pdf  (theorem pg 307)

Comment: The author is not claiming that $P\cap R=0$ ! He or she is claiming that all cases can be reduced to the case $P\cap R=0$, up to, say, changing $P,R$ in a way that does not harm what he or she is trying to prove (which you have not indicated so it's hard for us to help - claims that "without loss of generality, so and so" usually depend on what we're trying to prove)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following statements:

1. For all Jacobson rings $R$ and all prime ideals $P$ of $R[x]$ such that $R\cap P=0$, the ring $R[x]/P$ is semiprimitive.
2. For all Jacobson rings $R$ and all prime ideals $P$ of $R[x]$, the ring $R[x]/P$ is semiprimitive.

To answer your question, we have to prove $1\Rightarrow 2$.

Let $R$ be a Jacobson ring and let $P$ be a prime ideal of $R[x]$.
As you pointed out in your question, we have a ring isomorphism
$$R'[x]/P'\cong R[x]/P$$
where $R'=R/(P\cap R)$ is a Jacobson ring and $P'=\operatorname{Ker}\varphi$ is a prime ideal of $R'$ satisfying $P'\cap R'=0$.
By 1., $R'[x]/P'$ is semiprimitive, hence $R[x]/P$ is semiprimitive as well.
Thus 2. is proved.